# Trig sum and residues

Tags: closed-form, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I am interested in the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k 2\biggl[\sin\biggl(\frac{n\pi}{2k+2}\biggr)\biggr]^{-2g}
$$
where $k,g$ are integers. It is not too hard to show that this can also be expressed as
$$
-1-2\pi i\underset{t=0}{\operatorname{Res}}\biggl[\sin\biggl(\frac{\pi t}{2k+2}\biggr)\biggr]^{-2g}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi i t}-1}
$$

I also want the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k 2(-1)^n\biggl[\sin\biggl(\frac{n\pi}{2k+2}\biggr)\biggr]^{-2g}
$$
but this one -- I have not been able to express in a simpler form. Is there a representation similar to the previous one? Or even better, an even simpler representation, for both (not necessarily using residues)?

Comment: To what does apply the exponent ? The sine or its argument ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry, it applies to the sine. See edit. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing. Now, we know what is the problem.

Comment: Now posted to mathoverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418999/trigonometric-sum-and-residues